# Overwrite Python library dependencies

Tags: python

I've a module that imports some libraries which I want to overwrite. Example:

*module.py*

```
import md5

def test():
    print(md5.new("LOL").hexdigest())
```

*newfile.py*

```
class fake:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
    def hexdigest(self):
        return self.text
import sys
module = sys.argv[1] # It contains "module.py"
# I need some magic code to use my class and not the new libraries!
__import__(module)
```

**Edit 1**

I want to *avoid*/*skip* the import, not to execute it and then do a substitution.

**Edit 2**

Code fixed (this is just an example).

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate: I have to avoid the import, not do a substitution.

Comment: Another downvote? I will try to explain it better: I don't want to try to import the libraries, I want to make "import" harmless! :D

Comment: got it.. removed the comment. I was not the downvoter :)

Comment: Your code is a little confusing. You seem to be treating `a` and `b` as classes in `newfile.py`, but as modules in `module.py` - you can't really do that.

Comment: What does mean you want to skip the import? Do you realize you can put it in if statement?

Comment: @Igonato No, I can't touch them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your example doesn't make much sense, because you seem to be treating `a` and `b` as classes in `newfile.py`, but as modules in `module.py` - you can't really do that. I think you're looking for something like this...

*module.py*

```
from some_other_module import a, b
ainst = a("Wow")
binst = b("Hello")
ainst.speak()
binst.speak()
```

*newfile.py*

```
class a:
     def __init__(self, text):
         self.text = text
     def speak(self):
         print(self.text+"!")
class b:
     def __init__(self, text):
         self.text = text
     def speak(self):
         print(self.text+" world!")

# Fake up 'some_other_module'
import sys, imp
fake_module = imp.new_module('some_other_module')
fake_module.a = a
fake_module.b = b
sys.modules['some_other_module'] = fake_module

# Now you can just import module.py, and it'll bind to the fake module
import module
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an empty dicts as `globals` and `locals` to `__import__`. Remove whatever you want from them and then update your `globals` and `locals`.

```
tmpg, tmpl = {}, {}
__import__(module, tmpg, tmpl)
# remove undesired stuff from this dicts
globals.update(tmpg)
locals.update(tmpl)
```